# ReactJS error when accessing page using Server-side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, babeljs

I get this error when I load my ReactJS page

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>
    at invariant (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/tiny-invariant/dist/tiny-invariant.cjs.js:13:11)
    at Object.children (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:685:19)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3635:55)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
    at Object.renderToString (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3988:27)
    at ./server/index.js.app.get (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/server-build/index.js:215:71)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/Documents/Development/hmuweb/room/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I am assuming this error message is coming from my App.js file but I cannot seem to find where the error is occurring exactly. I tried re-structuring my App.js but when I do this, I receive another error saying the prop history is marked as required in the Router but its value is undefined. Also, that it cannot read property 'location' of undefined. Any idea how I can fix this issue? It started when I implemented SSR (Server Side Rendering).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Room from './App/pages/Room'
import Content from './App/pages/content';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Room} />
          <Route path="/watch" component={Content} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

webpack.server.js file incase needed

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './server/index.js',

  target: 'node',

  externals: [nodeExternals()],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "css-loader" },
      { test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/, use: 'file-loader'}
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {        
        'react-router-dom': path.join('./node_modules/react-router-dom')
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('server-build'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },

};
```

package.json file incase needed

```
{
  "name": "room",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "branca": "^0.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hls.js": "^0.13.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.10.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "object-encrypt-decrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server/index.js | react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev:build-server": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.server.js --mode=development -w",
    "dev:start": "nodemon ./server-build/index.js",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel build dev:*"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }
}
```

Index.js

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../src/App';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );
  const indexFile = path.join(__dirname + '../build/index.html');
  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
    }

    if (context.status === 404) {
      res.status(404);
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${app}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Where is the component Router in your application? The error indicates the router component from react router DOM is missing, is it in another component?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I apologize for not including my index.js. Please see my updated code above

Comment: Okay I see you import it but you aren’t wrapping App in it? Where are you actually using the component?

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't any other place I have the router components imported. I only used Switch, Route, and BrowserRouter and all was imported above in the index.js and App.js files. I even searched in the directory. @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: Right the error is saying that Switch needs to have a parent wrapping element at some level of BrowserRouter, HashRouter or Router. You don’t have that. You need to add it. You actually import it already in index.js but just don’t actually put into render. Wrap App With BrowserRouter.

Comment: I wrapped <App /> inside <BrowserRouter> and I am getting the same error, unfortunately. Do you think I have to change something in the App.js ?

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect the updated code?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I updated my index file above

Comment: That can’t be correct. You are double rendering App inside a class App, are you sure the code is correct?

Comment: Yes positive because before I did SSR, this code worked perfectly fine with no errors.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I switched to StaticRouter and it seems to work but it is saying that my index.html file inside my build folder is missing. I notice that when I run "npm run dev" the index.html file disappears from my build folder. Maybe I have an issue in my package.json scripts? Please check out my "const indexFile = path.resolve('../build/index.html');" code above in my index.js file.

Comment: Have you considered something like next js to handle all this for you?

Comment: I've tried using next.js but just got more issues. I seemed to fix the issue but it says that my build/index.html file is missing. It seems like it is re-building every time I run npm run dev. Any idea on this?

Comment: "I've tried using next.js but just got more issues" that is tough to troubleshoot without seeing code. Migrating to SSR can absolutely require core changes to your application. I see that your package.json has `jquery` and `bootstrap` included, you will likely encounter issues with trying to interact with the DOM in SSR as `document `and other browser APIs/objects are not available. Either way, glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of troubleshooting, I have finally fixed this issue.

Instead of passing the  directly inside the renderToString function, you have to nest it inside of a StaticRouter tag.

This answer helped me out: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/issues/1157#issuecomment-553044993

Also, I had to nest my Switch tag inside a Router tag like this:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Room} />
    <Route path="/watch" component={Content} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

After doing this I received another issue where my build index.html wasn't found. To fix this issue I had to tweak my project:

1. In ReactJS index.js file I had to switch my ReactDOM.render to ReactDOM.hydrate instead.
2. Created a server.js file inside my server folder where I moved my index.js code inside.
3. Inside my old server/index.js, I implemented my server-side support for JSX using @babel.

Here is my code:

server/index.js

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../src/App';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.get('^/$', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );
  const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html');
  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
    }

    if (context.status === 404) {
      res.status(404);
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${app}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

server/index.js

```
require('ignore-styles')

require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [/(node_module)/],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
})

require('./server');
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "room",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://hmutv.com/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "branca": "^0.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "hls.js": "^0.13.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.10.3",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "next": "^9.4.0",
    "object-encrypt-decrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "ssr": "node server/index.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```